# UIImageView with IBOutlet in Swift to see it in the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, swift, interface-builder

When I insert an Image to my View like this it works:

```
func loadSomeImage() {
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150))
    var image = UIImage(named: "myImage.jpg")
    imageView.image = image
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

My problem with this code is, that the ImageView is not shown in the Interface Builder.

When I write this code however, I get an error:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView
func loadSomeImage() {
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150))
    var image = UIImage(named: "myImage.jpg")
    imageView.image = image
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why is that? Can I insert an Image which is shown in the Interface Builder but has my own code implementation to change some features the Attribute Inspector can't change?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is the imageView connected to UIImageView from xib ?

Comment: Yes. If you mean that the instance imageView is connected to the UIImageView class in the Interface Builder?!

Comment: yes, I mean that. First don't do this: self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150)), because your imageView already is created, if you want to change it's frame, then modify it so : CGRect lFrame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150); self.imageView.frame = lFrame.

Comment: When you say "My problem with this code is, that the ImageView is not shown in the Interface Builder." are you sure ? try to change it's background color, maybe imageView is added to view but because image is not loaded, it's invisible.   imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that there are two different instances of UIImageView. One you are creating via interface builder and another one you are creating via code.

```
self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150))
```

This creates another instance of UIImageView and hence it is different from the imageView you have placed on interface builder. Simply remove this line of code and it will work. Also there is no need to addSubview again if you are using XIB.

Refine your code to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView
func loadSomeImage() {
    var image = UIImage(named: "myImage.jpg")
    self.imageView.image = image
}
```

This should be enough.

Comment: I have this code exactly, and I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  it seems that the image view is not initializing... ?

Comment: Are your Outlets connected in XIB?

Comment: I ctrl dragged from board to the file, so they should be.

Comment: actually its not exactly the same by outlet is @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!     <-- notice the ! at the end