# unexpectedly found nil UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` :

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class PhotosCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let photos = [
        UIImage(named: "photos_1"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_2"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_3"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_4"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_5"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_6"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_7"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_8"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_9"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_10"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_11"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_12"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_13"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_14"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_15"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_16"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_17"),
        UIImage(named: "photos_18")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return photos.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.image = self.photos[indexPath.row]
        // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {

    }
    */

}
```

And the cell VC:

```
import UIKit

class PhotoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

And in my assets I've got all the images listed it photos array -> http://prntscr.com/9tb7go

At this line, I get an error:

```
cell.imageView.image = self.photos[indexPath.row]
```

error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Comment: Not the image is nil, the `imageView` is!

Comment: how can it be nil when it's connected via outlet with `PhotoCollectionViewCell`? how do i fix this?

Comment: It probably is not connected correctly. In general: debug it - then you will see what is `nil`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140469/uiimageview-with-iboutlet-in-swift-to-see-it-in-the-interface-builder it seems you have a weak but you code as strong ref '!'

Comment: nah, even with weak & strong I get the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you do:

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

in your viewDidLoad.

If you have the cells in the storyboard, you should remove that line. The class is already registered in the Interface Builder, so that line will replace the entity created by IB, and it won't know who your imageView is.

If you have the cells in a separate xib and not in the storyboard, you have to register the nib and not the class, like this:

```
self.collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "name_of_your_nib_without_extension", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Comment: I do have a storyboard, not the xib.

Comment: @DragosStrugar if you have them in the storyboard, try commenting out the line `self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`. I think that replaces the one set in the storyboard, and it won't know who your imageView is

Comment: Great! I'll edit my answer to include this piece of information